# How do I avoid looping through multiple arrays

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to pass a class based on the url. Currently, the 2 for-loops are excecuted at all times. Is there a way to write it cleaner to avoid executing any unnecessary code?

```
const arrCommon = ['foo1', 'foo2', 'foo3', 'foo4'];
const arrOther = ['bar1', 'bar2', 'bar3'];

const activeUrl = window.location.href;
const activePage = activeUrl.substring(activeUrl.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);

for(let i=0; i<arrCommon.length; i++) {
    if (activePage == arrCommon[i])
         //if 'foo1, foo2 foo3 or foo4' add class to element 1
}

for(let i=0; i<arrOther.length; i++) {
    if (activePage == arrOther[i]) {
         //if 'bar1' add class to element 2
         //if 'bar2' add class to element 3
         //...
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're attempting to achieve, as you can put the loops together in multiple ways, but it may break your logic depending on what you want. Most methods will require putting both `arrCommon` and `arrOther` into a single list by doing this `[...arrCommon, ...arrOther]`.

Comment: @MisterJojo `collage-events, contributions, exams`

Comment: @MisterJojo it can be in either arrCommon or arrOther

Comment: You mistake is using Arrays with O(n) search complexity instead of a Set with O(1) lookup.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To avoid O(n) iterations, use a `Set` or `Map` instead, which should have "sublinear" lookup time - typically O(1).

```
const setCommon = new Set(['foo1', 'foo2', 'foo3', 'foo4']);
const mapOther = new Map(['bar1', el2], ['bar2', el3], ['bar3', el4]]);

const activeUrl = window.location.href;
const activePage = activeUrl.substring(activeUrl.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);

if (setCommon.has(activePage)) {
    ...
}

if (mapOther.has(activePage)) {
    let el = mapOther.get(activePage);
    ...
}
```

Comment: Indeed. But then, you'd still to iterate inside the second `if` block in order to know which element you'd need to add the class to, wouldn't you? I think I found a solution with a [simple JS object](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65700136/6419007). This would be O(1) too, right?

Comment: @EricDuminil ah, so that's what the OP meant by those comments!

Comment: This still required O(n) in order to create the Set and Map. If the original definition was switched from an array to an object to use as a dictionary, then you would get the benefit of O(1).

Comment: @TravisJ constructing an Object literal is still an O(n) operation under the hood - it's just done by the parser rather than the interpreter.  If anything though, I think the strength of this answer is that it does exactly express the intent, and does so very concisely.

Comment: Constructing an Object literal requires the amount of instructions for the properties to be created. Similar to constructing an array. However, calling Map or Set from that construction is an additional O(n) for each array. For example, this approach is twice as slow as the refactored approach shown below.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, however, this is really not necessary. O(n) operations, as you depict, aren't desirable targets for refactoring and constitute micro-optimizations. As such, this will more than likely harm readability at the insignificant gain of skipping a few instructions.

Here is how you would do it:

```
const arrCommon = ['foo1', 'foo2', 'foo3', 'foo4'];
const arrOther = ['bar1', 'bar2', 'bar3'];

const activeUrl = window.location.href;
const activePage = activeUrl.substring(activeUrl.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);

for(let i = 0, m = Math.max(arrCommon.length,arrOther.length); i < m; i++){
 if(activePage == arrCommon[i]){
  //if 'foo1, foo2 foo3 or foo4' add class to element 1

  // search complete
  break;
 }
 if(activePage == arrOther[i]){
   //if 'bar1' add class to element 2
   //if 'bar2' add class to element 3
   //...

  // search complete
  break;
 }
}
```

*Addendum*

It was raised in the comments that this approach results in more instructions executed. Indeed, because of the conditional short circuit this did execute more instructions in the given scenario, although only barely. In the example given by the OP it executes *one* extra instruction..... But still, the main point was to end up at O(n), which this is, and combine the multiple loops into one loop. Using a `break` here will still be O(n) but the combined loop will end up less instructions on average. In addition, the undefined check can be removed to reduce instructions. This is now faster for essentially every scenario in this design; if we were to be examining the situation where exceptionally large sets of lookups were in place, a different approach would be more applicable, but this is rather contained.

There is also the opportunity to use an O(1) lookup as shown in other answers, which still require O(n) setup so long as arrays are involved (creating the comparisons as an object would allow O(1) lookup and not require a mapping from the arrays). Without changing the definition of the items, that is not necessarily optimizing this any more than O(n), but is at least decent to read when composed properly.

Overall, this type of discussion is the exact reason why micro optimizing your code is a bad idea. It wastes time and effort at the most minimal of gain.

**Refactoring**

Refactoring into a form which would allow O(1) execution from the original design would result in the most performance, albeit not needed in this case as noted above with micro optimizations. This is solely as an aside.

```js
const activePage = 'foo3';

const commonStyles = {};
commonStyles.foo1 = commonStyles.foo2 = commonStyles.foo3 = commonStyles.foo4 = function(){
 // add class to element 1
 console.log('common');
};

const otherStyles = {};
otherStyles.bar1 = otherStyles.bar2 = otherStyles.bar3 = function(){
 //if 'bar1' add class to element 2
 //if 'bar2' add class to element 3
 //...
 console.log('other');
};

(commonStyles[activePage]&&commonStyles[activePage](),otherStyles[activePage]&&otherStyles[activePage]());
```

Comment: Wow! short and to-the-point!! Thanks :) +10

Comment: Why don't you use a `break` in your loop ?

Comment: Your answer is great. but I think Mister Jojo's solution is the most relavant answer to my question so marking it as the correct answer. Thanks once again!! :)

Comment: Complexity-wise this seems equal to the original or worse in some cases... If m and n are the lengths of the list and (without loss of symmetry) we take m to be larger... This one is order of 2*m+2*m+2*n+(m-n)=5m+n. The original is order of 3m+3n. Since m>=n, both are at least order of 6n, but in the case where m dominates n this one is order of 4m when the original is only order of 3m.

Comment: This probably executes *more* instructions.

Comment: I think this answer could be improved by pointing out that in practice, it's a bad idea to write code like this. If you want to close all the windows and doors, you should write "close all the windows and close all the doors"; you should not write "let *i* loop from 1 to the number of windows or the number of doors (whichever is greater), and for each such *i*, close the *i*th window (if any) and close the *i*th door (if any)." The latter is obviously much harder to read for no benefit at all.

Comment: @TannerSwett - The answer did state that though. There is no reason to change the OP's code as written, and in doing so you will harm readability; I showed an example of how improving performance can harm readability, even though it is faster.

Comment: @user - Neither of those statements is true.

Answer (score 2):

Unless I'm missing something, you could use a Javascript object as a dictionary (or a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)), in order to get the element id directly:

```js
const idByPage = {
  foo1: 1, foo2: 1, foo3: 1, foo4: 1,
  bar1: 2,
  bar2: 3,
  bar3: 4
}

var page = 'bar2';

if (idByPage.hasOwnProperty(page)) {
  console.log('element' + idByPage[page]);
  // Add class to ('element' + idByPage[page])
  // ...
}
```

Comment: Using plain objects as dictionaries is error prone as plain objects have built-in keys such as `toString`, `valueOf` and `constructor` (which, being just a single English word, is more prone to cause bugs). You could use `Object.create(null)` or `new Map()` instead.

Comment: @GustavoRodrigues: Thanks for the comment. Would `hasOwnProperty` solve this problem? If not, I'll refactor and use a Map instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `includes()` method of array in javascript.

Comment: It's similar to the more recent @Alnitak answer which uses `new Set()` and `.has()`, but using arrays. I think this one is simpler because it just requires replacing the loop with a method call, although [Set.prototype.has have better performance](https://dev.to/arnaud/using-array-prototype-includes-vs-set-prototype-has-to-filter-arrays-41fg).

Answer (score -1):

you can do that..

```js
const
    arrCommon  = ['foo1', 'foo2', 'foo3', 'foo4']
  , arrOther   = ['bar1', 'bar2', 'bar3']
  , activeUrl  = window.location.href
  , activePage = activeUrl.substring(activeUrl.lastIndexOf('/') + 1)
  ;

if (arrCommon.includes(activePage))  
  {
  // add class to element 1
  }
else
  {
  let idx2 = arrOther.indexOf(activePage)
  if (idx2 > -1) 
    {
    // add class to element idx2 + 2 ?
    }
  }
```

> Other possible way

```js
const
    elm_1 = document.querySelector('#element_1') 
  , elm_2 = document.querySelector('#element_2') 
  , elm_3 = document.querySelector('#element_3') 
  , elm_4 = document.querySelector('#element_4') 
  , elmRef = 
      { foo1: elm_1, foo2: elm_1, foo3: elm_1, foo4: elm_1
      , bar1: elm_2, bar2: elm_3, bar3: elm_4
      }
  , activeUrl  = window.location.href
  , activePage = activeUrl.substring(activeUrl.lastIndexOf('/') + 1)
  ;
if (elmRef[activePage])
  {
  elmRef[activePage].classList.add('classXY')
  }
```

Comment: Thanks. If you see the logic in my code, I don't think this will work.

Comment: Looks good. Thanks :) +10 but in a way this still loops through the unwated/irrelevant items?

Comment: @Fergoso The `.indexOf` method is not a loop, and it is arguably the most optimized way. (if not yes, if you care about assembly code, but in this case you will always find a loop whatever the way you go)

Comment: @Travis J's answer is great. but I think this solution is the most relavant answer to my question.

Comment: `.indexOf` is absolutely a loop - it's just one hidden inside a function call.

Comment: @MisterJojo in CS terms, it's an O(n) operation.  That's what really matters.

Comment: `Set` is mostly likely to be implemented using a HashTable, with iteration only required if multiple entries hit the same hash table entry.   Either way, the `Set` method also reads cleaner, IMHO.

Comment: @Alnitak Interested in looking at your suggestion

Comment: @Alnitak in this case my second solution will suit you better, it's also not an O(n) operation